# Aligning text to the centre of a button in HTML

Tags: html, css

All I need to do, is display some text, at the centre of my button, I have already defined a CSS file, which as the button button-primary class, which allocates a design for my button.

All I want to do is, place some text in the centre of the button, if I do
title = "Some Title", it appears behind the button, not in front of it.

```css
.button {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #E9EDF3;
  color: #535FD7 !important;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  height: 48px;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hero-inner">
      <div class="hero-copy">
        <h1 class="hero-title mt-0">Deep Algorithm by Sadman Sakib</h1>
        <p class="hero-paragraph">A personal portfolio/demonstration of all university and extra-curricular activites, beautifully packaged, in a modern and responsive Spring MVC Web Application</p>
        <div class="hero-cta">

          <p>View Projects</p> <input class="button button-primary" type="button">
          <div class="lights-toggle">
            <input id="lights-toggle" type="checkbox" name="lights-toggle" class="switch" checked="checked">
            <label for="lights-toggle" class="text-xs"><span>Turn me <span class="label-text">dark</span></span></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

I just want the view project to appear in the centre of the button

[image: Basically I am trying to get view projects in the centre of the button]

Comment: why don't you use text "View Projects" within the button itself?

Comment: It appears behind it, if I do title = "View Projects"

Comment: <input class="button button-primary" type="button" title ="View Projects" >

doesnt display it , I want the text to appear on top of the button

Comment: this will not work for you ? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/yrtfgq92/13/

Comment: You my friend are a genius it worked.

Comment: Can you post it as ur answer so i can mark it

Comment: As in my answer below all you have to do is put value="Submit" in the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a text:

```css
.button {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #535FD7;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<input class="button button-primary" type="button" value="View Projects">
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hero-inner">
      <div class="hero-copy">
        <h1 class="hero-title mt-0">Deep Algorithm by Sadman Sakib</h1>
        <p class="hero-paragraph">A personal portfolio/demonstration of all university and extra-curricular activites, beautifully packaged, in a modern and responsive Spring MVC Web Application</p>
        <div class="hero-cta">

          <button type="button">View Projects</button>

          <div class="lights-toggle">
            <input id="lights-toggle" type="checkbox" name="lights-toggle" class="switch" checked="checked">
            <label for="lights-toggle" class="text-xs"><span>Turn me <span class="label-text">dark</span></span></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `value="Submit"` inside the input.

```css
.button{display:inline-flex;
font-family:"IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing:0px;
font-weight:600;
line-height:16px;
text-decoration:none !important;
text-transform:uppercase;
background-color:#E9EDF3;
color:#535FD7 !important;
border:none;border-radius:2px;
cursor:pointer;
justify-content:center;padding:16px 32px;
height:48px;text-align:center;
white-space:nowrap;}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="hero-inner">
                <div class="hero-copy">
                    <h1 class="hero-title mt-0">Deep Algorithm by Sadman Sakib</h1>
                    <p class="hero-paragraph">A personal portfolio/demonstration of all university and extra-curricular activites, beautifully packaged, in a modern and responsive Spring MVC Web Application</p>
                    <div class="hero-cta">

                       <input class="button button-primary" type="button" value="Submit">
                        <div class="lights-toggle">
                            <input id="lights-toggle" type="checkbox" name="lights-toggle" class="switch" checked="checked"  >
                            <label for="lights-toggle" class="text-xs"><span>Turn me <span class="label-text">dark</span></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as your image reference

```css
.button {
  display: inline-flex;
  font-family: "IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 16px;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background-color: #E9EDF3;
  color: #535FD7 !important;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 16px 32px;
  height: 48px;
  text-align: center; 
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hero-inner">
      <div class="hero-copy">
        <h1 class="hero-title mt-0">Deep Algorithm by Sadman Sakib</h1>
        <p class="hero-paragraph">A personal portfolio/demonstration of all university and extra-curricular activites, beautifully packaged, in a modern and responsive Spring MVC Web Application</p>
        <div class="hero-cta">

          <p style="font-size:30px;line-height:0px;">View <br/> Projects <input class="button button-primary" type="button"></p> 
          <div class="lights-toggle">
            <input id="lights-toggle" type="checkbox" name="lights-toggle" class="switch" checked="checked">
            <label for="lights-toggle" class="text-xs"><span>Turn me <span class="label-text">dark</span></span></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.  Get rid of the p class and switch to anchor and then input class is not needed.  Also got rid of the height in the CSS to make it center quickly.

```
                <p class="hero-paragraph">A personal portfolio/demonstration of all university and extra-curricular activites, beautifully packaged, in a modern and responsive Spring MVC Web Application</p>
                <div class="hero-cta">

                   <a class="button button-primary">View Projects</a> 
                    <div class="lights-toggle">
                        <input id="lights-toggle" type="checkbox" name="lights-toggle" class="switch" checked="checked"  >
                        <label for="lights-toggle" class="text-xs"><span>Turn me <span class="label-text">dark</span></span></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>  
 

.button{display:inline-flex;
font-family:"IBM Plex Sans", sans-serif;
font-size:14px;
letter-spacing:0px;
font-weight:600;
line-height:16px;
text-decoration:none !important;
text-transform:uppercase;
background-color:#E9EDF3;
color:#535FD7 !important;
border:none;border-radius:2px;
cursor:pointer;
justify-content:center;padding:16px 32px;
text-align:center;
white-space:nowrap;}
```